Rules engine has slow down or takes longer to compile while firing rules [Drools]
I've a separate Java spring boot service as a rules engine. Which has controller and service to set focus on agenda groups as user or other service preferred. In my case i have 500 plus rules and 30 plus agenda groups. While i trigger the particular agenda groups it starts compile at the first trigger, afterwards it don't take time. When i keep on adding it takes time to first compile. Following things I'm suspecting: Please add on your thoughts.

I'm using for loops when i need to iterate over list of objects.
Larger number of rules.
Must be some problem with configurations.

Please share your thoughts. if you need any more input i can provide.
I didn't change anything yet. I just think to take some rules to another drools service. I want to make it faster or it should compile along with build.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621089/drools-performance-estimation


The less computation in when block the better, see this
Some performance investigation around session with 10K rules here
Rules compilation takes much time, but you can configure drools to precompile them, see this



Usually i don't write most lines of code in when block. i just capture objects in when block and i prefer process over then block by using java style code. Would it affect performance?


The point is that when block checks has optimizations on a drools level unless you do computations there (you mentioned loop iterations, was that in a when block?..) By computation I don't mean count of checks and field comparison, but code execution, like java functions call etc. Then block also gets computed, but this is 'java piece' which you can extract to a service and execute in parallel in your own thread pool executor or drools' one. Beware cartesian matches in when block (see one of the reference links), this works similarly to SQL and may degrade in performance the same way notably.

Precompiling rules (#3) definitely helps but it'll still take time to load them into memory of course, so need to plan for that. My app with ~70,000 precompiled rules still took like 20 minutes to start up due to the time to read all those kiebases into memory. (But it was much less than the 2+ hours it took without precompiling the rules.)
